# Can nopcommerce link to an exisitng second database easily?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, nopcommerce

I would appreciate any advice on this. I am not a developer. I am starting an online ebook business. Our backend data base runs on purely web based applications running on an SQL server 2008, .NET 4 / 64 bit environment. It contains all the stock information and pricing data. Due to the fact that we need to store 200,000 sku and rising all the stock information and pricing needs to be kept in the back end database.

Nopcommerce has been suggested as a good ecommerce database and cms system. Would it be suitable for this project? And does it have an established ability to pull data to the back end for viewing, browsing and also transfering data into the basket for customer purchases?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no out of the box support for second (backend) database.  However, as you may already know, it is an open source solution and can easily be extended to support what you are asking for. You will need to hire someone who is nopCommerce savvy.

Also, nopCommerce has a support forum ... you might have better luck asking your question there as the project contributors often visit that section. Good luck!

Comment: Just a note it is not very optimized for speed out of the box, and you need to do aggressive caching on the top of it.